# Rewrite higher-order function using recursion+lambdas

Tags: python, function, recursion, lambda

Here is a higher order function

```
def fn(f, n):
    def fn_inside(x):
        for i in range(n):
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return fn_inside
```

it can be replaced with recursion+lambdas in this way

```
def fn(f, n):
    return f if n == 1 else lambda y: fn(f, n-1)(f(y))
```

These two functions work well in this situation

sin(sin(sin(sin(sin(1))))) = 0.587181

```
from math import sin
f1 = fn(lambda x: "sin(%s)" % x, 5)
f2 = fn(lambda x: sin(x), 5)
print("%s = %f" % (f1("1"), f2(1)))
```

But the second function refuses to work here

```
print(fn(lambda x: sin(x), 0)(1000))
```

with ERROR

```
[Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

trying to increase the recursion limit i added

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

But nothing changed with error. Possibly a problem with negative infinity.

P.S. This function will work not only with sines. So you don't need to optimize it for recursive sine.
Could there be a simple solution here?

Comment: `return identity if n == 0`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're going for exactly, but your recursive algorithm only ends if n is 1 or greater: its base case is `n == 1` and n is updated by `n -= 1`. At 0, it just keeps decreasing without limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive version doesn't handle `n < 1` correctly. It recurses infinitely when this happens, because the base case `n == 1` is never reached.

The iterative version simply returns `x` when `n <= 0`, because the loop never runs (`range(0)` is an empty range). So you need to add that case to the recursive version.

```
def fn(f, n):
    if n < 1:
        return lambda y: y
    elif n == 1:
        return f
    else:
        return lambda y: fn(f, n-1)(f(y))
```

Comment: Do you keep the `n == 1` case for speed? If their demo with 1000 is representative of their actual usage, it won't matter.

Comment: Didn't really think about it, I just knew I needed to add the `<1` case.

Comment: This may sound a little silly, but what are the advantages of a method using recursion and lambdas over a method with a high-order function?

Comment: @Skeptic_0286 None that I can think of.

Comment: The recursive method preferred in functional programming. Python doesn't do tail recursion elimination like FP languages do, so it's not really a good idea here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and solution. I couldn't have done this so fast without you =)